# Cannot access to attribute of class

Tags: java

I have this method:

```
public V get(K key){
        TableEntry wanted = table[Math.abs(key.hashCode() % table.length)];
        while(wanted.getKey() != key && wanted != null) wanted = wanted.next;
        if(wanted.getKey() == key) return wanted.value;
        return null;
    }
```

Return wanted.value is red underlined in Eclipse and I getting message: cannot convert form object to V. My question is: why I can do that? I would like to return value (value is type V). Here is my code: 
[Java code](http://hastebin.com/iyapojewiv.java)

Comment: Its getValue() and you used only value. Modify your code instead of using wanted.value you used wanted.getValue()

Comment: you must return (V) wanted.getValue();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use generics in java, you need to declare the class using the generic types you are going to use.
`TableEntry` should be declared using generic types if you want `getValue()` to return of type other that Object, in your case, it should be:

```
TableEntry<K,V> wanted = table[Math.abs(key.hashCode() % table.length)];
```

this will make getValue() return V (if you wont declare it like that, K and V will automatically be defined as Object)